# Looking for a better way with Reporting Db server

Tags: sql-server, reporting

I have a "reporting" db server which is basically a clone of production using backup and restore in a stored proc to handle restore , user , permission etc.
Backups/restores happen 1x per day at a scheduled time.

Now they have a new db that they want on the report server and it is a pure OLTP db (right now I backup and restore it daily takes about 45 mins). The would like something a little more up-to-date just not realtime aka approx. with 2-4hours. I am in middle of converting from 2008 r2 to sqlserver 2014. 2008 r2 would give me replication or log shipping anybody have a better idea? Would really like a better idea as I am a single dba shop on call 24/7 365 and enjoy ability to sleep thru the night.
Thanks
kris

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 options ...

If you are using

- Enterprise edition then

  - SQL server 2014 Enterprise edition will give you AlwaysON Availablity groups .. which you can use to offload reporting on secondary.
- Standard edition then

  - You can use logshipping with delaying on transaction logs on secondary in STANDBY mode. The only caveat will be that when the transaction logs are being restored, all the users will be kicked out of the secondary server.

*(I am not mentioning **database mirroring**, but you can use that (even though it is marked as deprecated. You can create [database snapshot on secondary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx) and every 2-3 hrs, you can generate a new one since your requirement is - data can be stale 2-4hours)*

When using backup/restore method, make sure that you have enabled Instant file initialization and you are using backup compression. That will cut down the backup/restore time.

Comment: Thanks I do use compression will check on instant file initialization. Unfortunately we use Standard Edition do to costs against my recommendation btw.

Comment: when you say kicked out of secondary server you mean out of that DB not ALL the db's on the server right?

Comment: `Unfortunately we use Standard Edition do to costs against my recommendation`. Then explore Logshipping with delaying of log files or better automate your backup/restore using tsql or powershell. For your 2nd question `when you say kicked out of secondary server you mean out of that DB not ALL the db's on the server right?` Yes, for that particuliar DB only since Logshipping works at per database level.

Comment: AlwaysOnGroups seem to be a great way to replace/not implement transactional replication however AlwaysONGroups do not appear to be in standard edition even in sqlserver 2014/2016 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)but something called Basic availability groups is Support for 2 nodes. What is a basic availability group?